# T-sql,Mvc, SQL,MAIL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, email

I have a table with manager login id which doesnt have domain name while sending mail it should automatically fetch domain name to send mail in sql , i used below query , i need to add @xxx.com automatically to recipient mail..
begin

```
Use [register ]
DECLARE @Receipientlist varchar(8000)
SET @ReceipientList =
              STUFF((SELECT ';' + Manager_Login_Id FROM dbo.Idea FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

SELECT
    Idea_Id,Login_Id,Manager_Login_Id,Idea_Date_Of_Submission,Idea_Status ='PENDING'
FROM
    dbo.Idea
WHERE
    Manager_Login_Id IS NOT NULL and Idea_Date_Of_Submission <= DATEADD(day, -5, GETDATE());

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        profile_name = '',
        recipients = @Receipientlist,
        body = 'The DB has changed',
        subject = 'DB Change';
```

Answer (score 0):

If your first `@RecipientList` variable contains the *DOMAIN* users then you can simply concatenate the mail domain to `Manager_Login_Id`

```
Use [register ]
DECLARE @Receipientlist varchar(8000)
SET @ReceipientList =
              STUFF((SELECT ';' + Manager_Login_Id+'@xxx.com ' FROM dbo.Idea FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

SELECT
    Idea_Id,Login_Id,Manager_Login_Id,Idea_Date_Of_Submission,Idea_Status ='PENDING'
FROM
    dbo.Idea
WHERE
    Manager_Login_Id IS NOT NULL and Idea_Date_Of_Submission <= DATEADD(day, -5, GETDATE());

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        profile_name = '',
        recipients = @Receipientlist,
        body = 'The DB has changed',
        subject = 'DB Change';
```

Comment: I concatenated but dont want table values to be affected.below is code used query is succesfull but unable to send mail.

Comment: table values aren't affected since you are doing it in a variable (`@Receipientlist`). If the `sp_send_mail` fails you should post the error message

Comment: mail is queued but in mail log its showing unable to send mail showing recipient must be specified

Comment: @AshokHoskera it means your query doesnt provide expected result: try to replace the `exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` command with a `SELECT ReceipientList ` and check which is its current value