# mail sending from sql

Tags: sql-server, email, jobs

Sql executing result but mail not sent, error is recipient must be specified.

I have recipient list declared and added multiple mails to recipient list where query executed and multiple recipients mails displayed.

```
BEGIN 
 Use [register ] 
 DECLARE Receipientlist varchar(8000) 
 SET ReceipientList = STUFF(
     ( 
       SELECT ';' + Manager_Login_Id 
       FROM dbo.Login 
       FOR XML PATH('')
     ),1,1,'') 

 SELECT Idea_Id, Login_Id, Manager_Login_Id, Idea_Date_Of_Submission, Idea_Status ='PENDING' 
 FROM dbo.Idea 
 WHERE Manager_Login_Id IS NOT NULL 
   and Idea_Date_Of_Submission <= DATEADD(day, -5, GETDATE()); 

 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail profile_name = ' ', recipients = Receipientlist, body =' ',subject=' ', 

 END
```

Comment: You've posted a question and forgot to post a question! Whoops! You also forget to include your SQL when you posted as well, D'oh! [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50716392/edit) your question and have another go. :)

Comment: Begin

 Use [register ]

 DECLARE Receipientlist varchar(8000)

SET ReceipientList = STUFF((SELECT ';' + Manager_Login_Id  FROM dbo.Login FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

 SELECT Idea_Id,Login_Id,Manager_Login_Id,Idea_Date_Of_Submission,Idea_Status ='PENDING' FROM dbo.Idea
WHERE  Manager_Login_Id IS NOT NULL  and Idea_Date_Of_Submission <= DATEADD(day, -5, GETDATE());
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
        profile_name = '   ',
        recipients = Receipientlist,body ='  ',subject=' ', end

Comment: put your question in your main post by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50716392/edit) it, not here as comment

Comment: @AshokHoskera I can't read that code, you posted it in the comments. You've already had 2 links on how to the editting page. Also, you're still missing your question.

Comment: Just at a glance. I would expect that sp_send_dbemail stored procedure to expect a list of e-mail addresses. Not a list of ID's. So that Manager_Login_Id field contains e-mails then?

Comment: I just noticed you've posted the same question some days ago.. why did you repost it? You could edit, or answer to people who was trying to help you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50676361/t-sql-mvc-sql-mail/50677267#50677267

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-sql,Mvc, SQL,MAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50676361/t-sql-mvc-sql-mail)

Answer (score 1):

That SQL you have (kindly formatting by LukStorms) is incomplete, it won't run. Your statement has a "wayward" comma at the end:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail profile_name = ' ', recipients = Receipientlist, body =' ',subject=' ', <-- What is this comma here for?
```

The reason, however, your SQL isn't working, apart from the wayward comma, is your syntax is also wrong for your parameters and variables. For both, their names begin with an `@`. Thus, the correct syntax would be:

```
USE [register ] 
DECLARE @Recipientlist varchar(8000); --Variables begin with a @. Also changed the name to the correct spelling
SET @Recipientlist = STUFF((SELECT ';' + Manager_Login_Id 
                            FROM dbo.[Login] --Login is a reserved word, i suggest using a different name for your table.
                            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'');


SELECT Idea_Id,
       Login_Id,
       Manager_Login_Id,
       Idea_Date_Of_Submission,
       Idea_Status AS PENDING
FROM dbo.Idea 
WHERE Manager_Login_Id IS NOT NULL 
  AND Idea_Date_Of_Submission <= DATEADD(day, -5, GETDATE());  

 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = ' ',
                              @recipients = @Recipientlist,
                              @body =' ',--Why are you sending an empty body?
                              @subject=' ';--, Removed the comma, although I suggest having a subject too.
```